# can we use the inbuilt Fingerprint scanner to use as attendance scanner?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to create an **attendance application** using *Android smartphone* and  *inbuild Fingerprint Hardware*, were few supervisors will have an application on their Android smartphone. they will register new user's finger data using their smartphone and they have to upload in a server as a ByteCode or some other format and whenever the employee is logging in using an app, the finger will be checked with the server by sending scanned  ByteCode or some other format data to a server to compare an authorise the user and make him login.
I was checking this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/package-summary.html,  this looks like only the user's finger which is enroled in os can be verified. but I want to use the same hardware to record many employees finger and that should sav in server an whenever app installed in an Android smartphone, it is supposed to be compared and provide the authentication to log in.

Comment: Any of the enrolled fingerprints on the device can be used for authentication. You won't know which one it was - only whether the authentication succeeded or not. Also, many devices have a pretty low limit for how many fingerprints you can enroll. So no, your app won't be possible to develop using Android's official fingerprint API.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is not supported, for privacy reasons.

You are welcome to look at third-party external fingerprint scanners and see if they give you the actual biometric data back that you could use. However, I recommend that you discuss this with qualified legal counsel, so you know what criminal and civil liability you may be under personally. Biometrics is a *very* sensitive area, and so you need to understand what is and is not allowed in your area.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference link that describes the above behavior of android operating system?

Answer (score 0):

As you found in the docmuntation this cannot be done via android APIs. You would probably need custom android image (modity the opensource android) to achieve this functionality